# Updating Textbox in a templateField with button

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, templatefield

it's my first time asking a question here in stackoverflow so please bear with me. I am creating a webpage using asp.net, I have GridView with columns set as databound except 1 template field, within the template field is a textbox and a button. I want to update the value of the textbox using an outside button(a button in the same page, but outside the gridview), can anyone show/tell me how to do that?

GridView1 is the ID of the gridView,

here is the templateField:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Template Field1">
    <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="textboxs">
         </asp:TextBox>
         <asp:Button runat="server" ID="buttons" Text="S"/>
     </ItemTemplate>
     <HeaderStyle Width="15px" />
     <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
</asp:TemplateField>

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click1" Text="Button" />
```

here is the Code Behind:

```
protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewCode.Rows[0].Cells[10].Text = "Some Text";
}
```

I think the problem is that the templatefield has a textbox and a button, please correct me if I am wrong.

BTW I can't remove the button in the templatefield, it has to be a textbox with a button. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You need to post up the code you have and what you have tried ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // First bind you grid again over here other wise it will lost data

    GridView1.DataSource = you List of Objects or DataTable;
    GridView1.DataBind();

    foreach (GridViewRow gvr in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        if (gvr.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            // to fill all text boxes
            TextBox textboxs = gvr.FindControl("textboxs") as TextBox;
            textboxs.Text = "You text";


            // to fill specific text box
            // use gvr.DataItem to check aging specific data item using if and then
            // textboxs.Text = "You text";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Jignesh Suvariya. Your code helped me a lot. :)

Answer (score 1):

Without further code from you, something along the lines of:

```
protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   TextBox textboxs = GridView.Rows[2].FindControl("textboxs");
   textboxs.Text = "New Text Here";
}
```

where index `2` is the row index of your gridview's databound data

Answer (score 1):

```
You can use a code like this:

    for (int i = 0; i < GridView.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        GridViewRow gvr = GridView.Rows[i];
        Textbox txtBox= (Textbox)gvr.Cells[0].FindControl("textbox_id");
        txtBox.Text = "Your new text here";
    }
```

This will replace the text box of each row and you can impose conditions for replacing it in specific rows.